# Ursina scene change

Tags: python, menu, scene, ursina

I recently started playing around with Ursina engine for python and i would like to change scene for a game i am working on.

Basically, i would like to do what it shown in this video (made with kivy):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaYn4XdieCs

I tried creating a class which inherit from scene and then passing that as the parent arguments but i keep getting errors when creating the "scene" object.

Is there an easy way to reproduce that video?

Thx!

Comment: Please show us your code and errors, in the form of a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Entity for each scene and parent things to them. You can then enable/disable them as you wish. Inheriting Entity also works, but not `scene`